# arctic sea ice data by year

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I want to demonstrate the usefulness of regression lines to my class, and I was hoping to do so with some data about the Arctic sea ice.  What I'd like is the maximal area covered by the ice per year, since 1980 (or thereabouts).  Failing that, just any kind of data regarding the ice that can show the negative linear trend over a sizable amount of time.  A google search didn't give me the actual numbers, so does anyone know where I can find the exact data?  Thanks!

Comment: http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/WorldOfChange/sea_ice.php  plus the links included in that article.

Comment: Maybe you can contact the authors of this lovely site with a viewable-controllable frame of ice levels: http://www.nasa.gov/topics/earth/features/thick-melt.html

Comment: Why specifically do you want to demonstrate the usefulness with an artic ice data set.  It seems there are a wealth of other data sets that could do the job as well or better.  is it because this is some kind of a geology course?

Comment: You may also find this site quite useful for resources and data: http://neven1.typepad.com/

Comment: thanks for the help.  If one of you just posts your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also find this site quite useful for resources and data: neven1.typepad.com

Note: there are many other examples of data where you can use visualization to make it come alive to the viewers.

There are even cities putting out tons of data (UK leads, US no. 2, for example San Francisco) and you can see a TED talk on the matter.

HTH ~A

Comment: Nice $\large \checkmark$ and $\; +\, |\,i^2|\;$

Comment: @amWhy: Hi, hope all is well, have had a very busy day finishing my talk, finally happy with it (mostly). Came across another very rude person on mse. Hope u r having a better day!

Comment: @amWhy: relatively new user. I have seen many people on here that would have a hard time working in the real world by their attitude alone. That will not fly in the workplace today. Yes, I have noticed quite a few creative +1 comments! :-)